# Webpack not finding paths for fonts and no dist dir

Tags: javascript, webpack, font-face

So I'm getting started recently with Webpack, everything is working fine except for two things:

- No dist output folder
- Webpack is not recognising @font-face relative paths

Here is my project structure:

[image: folder structure]

Here is my webpack.config.js:

```js
const HtmlWebpackPlugin    = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");
const webpack              = require('webpack');
const CopyWebpackPlugin    = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const UglifyJSPlugin       = require('uglifyjs-webpack-plugin');
const path                = require('path');
require('dotenv').config();

const ENV = process.env.APP_ENV;
const isTest = ENV === 'test'
const isProd = ENV === 'prod';

function setDevTool() {  // function to set dev-tool depending on environment
  if (isTest) {
    return 'inline-source-map';
  } else if (isProd) {
    return 'source-map';
  } else {
    return 'eval-source-map';
  }
}

const config = {
  devtool: setDevTool(),
}

if (isProd) {
  config.plugins.push(
    new UglifyJSPlugin(),
    new CopyWebpackPlugin([{
      from: __dirname + '/assets/'
    }])
  );
}

module.exports = config;

module.exports = {
  entry: __dirname + "/src/js/index.js", // webpack entry point. Module to start building dependency graph
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/dist/', // Folder to store generated bundle
    filename: 'bundle.js',  // Name of generated bundle after build
    publicPath: '/' // public URL of the output directory when referenced in a browser
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      fonts: path.resolve(__dirname, '/assets/fonts')
    }
  },
  module: {  // where we defined file patterns and their loaders
      rules: [
        {
          test: /\.js$/,
          use: 'babel-loader',
          exclude: [
            /node_modules/
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(sass|scss)/,
          use: [
            {
              loader: 'style-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'css-loader'
            },
            {
              loader: 'sass-loader'
            }
          ],
        },
        {
          test: /\.css$/,
          use: [
            MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            'css-loader'
          ]
        },
        {
          test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
          use: {
            loader: "file-loader",
            options: {
              name: "fonts/[name].[ext]",
              outputPath: 'fonts/'
            },
          }
        }
      ]
  },
  plugins: [  // Array of plugins to apply to build chunk
      new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
          template: __dirname + "/index.html",
          inject: 'body'
      }),
      new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
        filename: '[name].css',
        chunkFilename: '[id].css'
      }),
      new webpack.DefinePlugin({
        API_KEY: JSON.stringify(process.env.API_KEY)
      })
  ],
  devServer: {  // configuration for webpack-dev-server
      contentBase: './assets',  //source of static assets
      port: 7700, // port to run dev-server
  }
};
```

So basically, I'm loading fonts like this:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'Metropolis';
src: url('../../../assets/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Medium.woff2') format('woff2'),
   url('../../../assets/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Medium.woff') format('woff'),
   url('../../../assets/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Medium.ttf') format('truetype');
}
```

Here is the output when I run `webpack-dev-server --history-api-fallback --inline --progress`

[image: terminal output]

I've tried so many tutorials and on my own, even aliases is not working.

Answer (score 0):

Answers:

1. There is no `dist` folder- you are running `webpack-dev-server` it is suitable for dev only, it has performance optimisation that "saves" the files in memory (not the disk).
   In order to access them you can address your assets to the `http://localhost:7700/bundle.js` (relevant to your config only).

There is another option, to use [`write-file-webpack-plugin`](https://github.com/gajus/write-file-webpack-plugin), that will force dev-server to write to disk, it will disable the performance benefit.

2. Regarding the second question, webpack resolves dependency tree of requires, and css `url()` directive, each such require should be relative to its parent, therefore, in your case, the font file path should be relative to the css file that "requires" it.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I get it for the dist folder, but for fonts I didn't get it well, I used `../../../assets/fonts/metropolis/Metropolis-Medium.woff2` as relative path, but still get the same error

Comment: I figured it out :), there was an extra level in the fonts path, now everything is working as expected, just replaced `url-loader` with `file-loader` for fonts:
`{
  test: /\.(ttf|eot|woff|woff2)$/,
  use:  {
     loader: 'filer-loader',
     options: {
       name: '[name].[ext]',
       outputPath: 'fonts/'
     }
  }
}
`